# Pytrends Fetch Last Hours Data

Tags: python, search, python-requests, google-trends

I am trying to fetch the last N hours trends data of a keyword. To do that, I use the Pytrends package, using the `get_historical_interest()` function. Even though Google Trends' webpage does display the data up to now, it seems that the Pytrends API can't retrieve the last 3 hours. My code is this:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq


data = TrendReq().get_historical_interest(
    keywords=['bitcoin'],
    year_start=2022,
    month_start=2,
    day_start=21,
    hour_start=0,
    year_end=2022,
    month_end=2,
    day_end=21,
    hour_end=15
)

print(data)
```

And this is the result I get:

```
date                                   
2022-02-21 00:00:00       82      False
2022-02-21 01:00:00       74      False
2022-02-21 02:00:00       76      False
2022-02-21 03:00:00       72      False
2022-02-21 04:00:00       75      False
2022-02-21 05:00:00       78      False
2022-02-21 06:00:00       81      False
2022-02-21 07:00:00       79      False
2022-02-21 08:00:00       77      False
2022-02-21 09:00:00       74      False
2022-02-21 10:00:00       77      False
2022-02-21 11:00:00       84      False
2022-02-21 12:00:00      100      True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It looks like the API can't retrieve the last 3 hours of data. Is there something wrong with the Pytrends API? Should I use an alternative API to fetch the most recent data?
Thanks in advance.